# How to display upload progress using C# HttpClient PostAsync

Tags: c#, file-upload, xamarin, httpclient, progress

A am creating a file upload app for Android and iOS using Xamarin PCL and i have managed to implement file upload and some sort of progress bar, but it is not working properly.

I saw some answers on stack overflow for displaying download progress, but i want to notify my users about **upload** progress and did not find any solution.

Here is my code:

```
public static async Task<string> PostFileAsync (Stream filestream, string filename, int filesize) {
        var progress = new System.Net.Http.Handlers.ProgressMessageHandler ();

        //Progress tracking
        progress.HttpSendProgress += (object sender, System.Net.Http.Handlers.HttpProgressEventArgs e) => {
            int progressPercentage = (int)(e.BytesTransferred*100/filesize);
            //Raise an event that is used to update the UI
            UploadProgressMade(sender, new System.Net.Http.Handlers.HttpProgressEventArgs(progressPercentage, null, e.BytesTransferred, null));
        };

        using (var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(progress)) {
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent ("------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString ("x"))) {
                content.Add (new StreamContent (filestream), "Filedata", filename);
                using (var message = await client.PostAsync ("http://MyUrl.example", content)) {
                    var result = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("Upload done");
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Some sort of progress is displayed, but when the progress reaches 100%, the file is not uploaded yet. Message "Upload done" is also printed some time after i have received the last progress message.

Maybe the progress is displaying bytes sent out of the device and not already uploaded bytes, so when it says, that it is 100%, all of the bytes are just sent out but not yet received by the server?

**Edit:** Tried this solution: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56716/plans-to-add-webclient-to-pcl and it works a bit better.

Answer (score 8):

## Simplest way to upload file with progress

You can get accurate progress by tracking the `Position` of the `FileStream` of the file that you are going to upload.

This demonstrates how to do that.

```
FileStream fileToUpload = File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.mp3");

HttpContent content = new StreamContent(fileToUpload);
HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage{
    Content=content,
    RequestUri = new Uri(--yourUploadURL--)
}

bool keepTracking = true; //to start and stop the tracking thread
new Task(new Action(() => { progressTracker(fileToUpload, ref keepTracking); })).Start();
var result = httpClient.SendAsync(msg).Result;
keepTracking = false; //stops the tracking thread
```

And `progressTracker()` function is defined as

```
void progressTracker(FileStream streamToTrack, ref bool keepTracking)
{
    int prevPos = -1;
    while (keepTracking)
    {
        int pos = (int)Math.Round(100 * (streamToTrack.Position / (double)streamToTrack.Length));
        if (pos != prevPos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pos + "%");

        }
        prevPos = pos;

        Thread.Sleep(100); //update every 100ms
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 very simple indeed! Just one extra detail if `httpClient.SendAsync(msg).Result` throws an exception (e.g. because the upload failed due to a network error) then `keepTracking` will never be set to `false` and the `progressTracker()` function will loop forever!

Comment: For future readers: this is easily solved by wrapping `SendAsync` in a `try/finally` that sets `keepTracking` to false in the `finally` block

Comment: Doesn't work in Blazor, as the file stream position hits 100% immediately.

Comment: @Abraham: For me, it looks like, this solution is not thread safe. To realize this, the [`Stream.Synchronized`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.synchronized) method should be used for `fileToUpload`.

Answer (score -2):

This is because you are doing the math wrong.

Change : `int progressPercentage = (int)(e.BytesTransferred*100/filesize);`

To : `int progressPercentage = (int)(e.BytesTransferred/filesize) *100;`

use this code instead:

```
    double bytesOut = double.Parse(e.BytesTransferred.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(filesize.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesOut / totalBytes * 100;
```

or you can simply use `e.ProgressPercentage`

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem. It was because the data was getting buffered and only sent at the end. I ended up using `HttpWebRequest` with `SendChunked` set to true and `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` set to false, then manually writing the data in the request stream.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov As this is an old issue, i don't remember how i solved this issue, but judging by the edit on my initial problem, i think i might have used the code from the Xamarin forum link.