# Get upload progress from MultipartFormDataContent and StreamContent

Tags: c#, .net

Consider this small code below:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var str = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("movie.mp4"));
multiForm.Add(str, "to_upload", "1.mp4");
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://example.com/upload", multiForm);
```

As you can see I'm using `StreamContent` and `MultipartFormDataContent` to upload a file. My question is it is possible to somehow get the upload progress from HttpClient? Or any other way to get upload progress?

Comment: You mean the progress of the uploaded data right ?

Comment: @HariHaran yes; I can use another thread for publishing progress.

Comment: You can Implement HttpClient class as : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320238/how-to-display-upload-progress-using-c-sharp-httpclient-postasync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `ProgressableStreamContent` from [here](https://github.com/jeffijoe/httpclientgoodies.net/blob/master/src/Jeffijoe.HttpClientGoodies/ProgressableStreamContent.cs)

or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378457/c-httpclient-file-upload-progress-when-uploading-multiple-file-as-multipartfo/41392145) answer

and a simple usage can be

```
 var progress = new ProgressableStreamContent (
     requestContent, 
     4096,
     (sent,total) => {
        Console.WriteLine ("Uploading {0}/{1}", sent, total);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Here is also an example of using the whole thing: https://gist.github.com/HirbodBehnam/272aa5e4b82c2fb05583d095f2224861

Comment: @HirbodBehnam nice